# cannot use react-spring (Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-spring

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";
function App() {
  const props = useSpring({ to: { opacity: 1 }, from: { opacity: 0 } });
  return <animated.div style={props}>I will fade in</animated.div>;
}

export default App;
```

From the code above, I am trying to use the useSpring hook from react-spring library that i just downloaded using `npm i react-spring` but it seems to be throwing out this error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dgLk.png)

I tried using other hooks from 'react' and it worked (useState, useEffect). it is only the hooks from 'react-spring' that doesn't work so I can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The versions of my packages were:

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-spring": "^9.4.4",
```

Upgrading `react-spring`'s version to `9.4.5-beta.1` solved the issue for me.

```
"react-spring": "^9.4.5-beta.1",
```

You can also try downgrading react and react DOM.
For e.g. you could downgrade both to 17.0.2. Keep in mind you would have to change your index.js to use `ReactDOM.render` instead of `ReactDOM.createRoot`:

Answer (score 0):

The following did not work for me as per other post:

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-dom": "18.1.0",
"react-spring": "^9.4.5-beta.1",
```

Upgrading React and react-spring to latest did however:

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-spring": "^9.5.2"
```